# Change category attribute within installation script

Tags: magento, installation

I have my module. This module has installation script where should be add custom image field to categories.

```
$setup->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'additional_image', array(
    'type'              => 'varchar',
    'backend'           => 'catalog/category_attribute_backend_image',
    'label'             => 'Additional Image',
    'input'             => 'image',
    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'visible'           => 1,
    'required'          => 0,
    'user_defined'      => 0,
    'default'           => '',
    'position'          => 6,
));
```

After that it must change captions other image fields (Image, Thumbnail). How I can get this system's fields and change their?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup::updateAttribute()` method.

Comment: Can you help me with second and third arguments?

Answer (score 1):

This is a long way off but someone else may need the information.

```
Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup::updateAttribute()
```

has 5 arguments, 3 of which are necessary.

I am going to use the example of a custom customer attribute:

```
$entityTypeId = 'customer'
$id = 'my_custom_attribute_code'
$field = 'is_used_for_customer_segment'
$value = '1'
$sortOrder = Not Needed
```

So as you can see I am using the customer entity to update the attribute.  I am updating my custom attribute with attribute id (code) my_custom_attribute_code.  The field in this attribute that I am udpating is the is_used_for_customer_segment and setting the value to yes(1).

Here is an example of how to do this as an update.

```
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->updateAttribute('customer', 'my_custom_attribute_code', 'is_used_for_customer_segment', '1');

$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: Works perfectly, however please note that you will have to use the exact column name as it is used in the *eav_attribute* table, not the aliased attribute code, if you want to update a default attribute. Using "*label*" as the attribute code won't work, you'll have to use "*frontend_label*" instead!